# Merging dataframes to include columns indicating which dataframes the rows belong to

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframes(a is hashable, b is unhashable)

```
   Foo              
    a   b           
A   1   2       
B   1   3       
C   0   4       

 Bar
a   b
A   1   2
D   0   6
```

If the index or the codes (A,B,C,D in this case) are the same, the a and b must be the same.
I want to know how can merge these two dataframe showing where the column belongs like this.

```
    a   b   Foo   Bar
A   1   2    1     1
B   1   3    1     0
C   0   4    1     0
D   0   6    0     1
```

What is the most efficient way to get this dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One row solution if no `NaN` in data with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and outer join by [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html). But is necessary add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from `index`, because need merge columns with index together. Last [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for create `index` back.

Parameter `on` can be removed, because joined on same columns in both DataFrames.

```
df = pd.merge(Foo.reset_index().assign(Foo=1), 
              Bar.reset_index().assign(Bar=1), how='outer') \
       .fillna(0) \
       .set_index('index') \
       .rename_axis(None) \
       .astype(int)
print (df)
   a  b  Foo  Bar
A  1  2    1    1
B  1  3    1    0
C  0  4    1    0
D  0  6    0    1
```

If possibble `NaN`s then use subset only for indicator columns:

```
df = pd.merge(Foo.reset_index().assign(Foo=1), 
              Bar.reset_index().assign(Bar=1), how='outer') \
       .set_index('index') \
       .rename_axis(None) 
df[['Foo','Bar']] = df[['Foo','Bar']].fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   a    b  Foo  Bar
A  1  NaN    1    1
B  1  3.0    1    0
C  0  4.0    1    0
D  0  6.0    0    1
```

---

`pandas` has implemented similar way by parameter `indicator`:

```
df = pd.merge(Foo.reset_index().assign(Foo=1), 
              Bar.reset_index().assign(Bar=1), how='outer', indicator='indicator') \
       .set_index('index') \
       .rename_axis(None) 
print (df)
   a  b  Foo  Bar   indicator
A  1  2  1.0  1.0        both
B  1  3  1.0  NaN   left_only
C  0  4  1.0  NaN   left_only
D  0  6  NaN  1.0  right_only
```

Comment: Thx, but what if the column b is a numpy array which cannot be hashed

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using `df.merge`:

```
df1['Foo'] = 1
df2['Bar'] = 1
out = df1.merge(df2, on=['a', 'b'], how='outer').fillna(0).astype(int)

print(out)
   a  b  Foo  Bar
0  1  2    1    1
1  1  3    1    0
2  0  4    1    0
3  0  6    0    1
```

Comment: Thx, but what if the column b is a numpy array which cannot be hashed

Comment: @niukasu But your original question didn't ask about that. Please ask a separate question in a new thread. That would require a total different answer.